# How to store HTML inputs into Javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a random number generator and I would like to store the input of the max number in a variable so I can find a random number. I don't know how to do this. Can you help?

```html
<html>
<p><font size="6"><center>Welcome to the Random Number Generator</center></font></p>

<script>

var x = 1;

function getRandomNumber()
{
 while (x>=amountOfNumbers)
 {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumber);
 }
}

function alertTheNumber()
{
 alert(maxNumber);
}

</script>

<p>What would you like your max number to be and how many random numbers do you want?</p>
<p><form action="form"></p>
 My max number is <input id="maxNumber" min="1" max="100000000" type="number" name="maxNumber"><br>
 I want <input id="amountOfNumbers" min="1" max="20" type="number" name="amountOfNumbers"><br>

<button type="button" onclick"getRandomNumber()">Generate!</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you *more specific*?

Comment: Good suggestion Nehal. Btw have u tried `getElementById()` . from ur question title ,i guess u should look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getElementById` to get the specific input element `value`

```
<html>
<p><font size="6"><center>Welcome to the Random Number Generator</center></font></p>

<script>

var x = 1;

function getRandomNumber()
{
    var amountOfNumbers = parseInt( document.getElementById( "amountOfNumbers" ).value ); //get the value of amount of numbers to be generated
    var maxNumber = parseInt( document.getElementById( "maxNumber" ).value ); //get the maxvalue of a number should be
    var numbers = [];
    while (x<=amountOfNumbers)
    {
        numbers.push( Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumber); //push the numbers in an array
    }
    console.log( numbers.join( "," ) ); //show the numbers on console separated by comma
    alert( numbers.join( "," ) );
}

</script>

<p>What would you like your max number to be and how many random numbers do you want?</p>
<p><form action="form"></p>
    My max number is <input id="maxNumber" min="1" max="100000000" type="number" name="maxNumber"><br>
    I want <input id="amountOfNumbers" min="1" max="20" type="number" name="amountOfNumbers"><br> numbers

<button type="button" onclick"getRandomNumber()">Generate!</button>
</html>
```

Comment: I keep getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list." I have tried removing the semicolon and it still didn't work. Could you help? This is on line 15.

Comment: @willfrankel put a ) before semicolon;

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandomNumber() {

    var max = Number(document.getElementById("maxNumber").value);

    //...
```